# Dovecot user lookup fails when using username@domain format

Tags: email, postfix, freebsd, dovecot

I have Dovecot v2.0.11 installed on a FreeBSD server and the user lookups for incoming email addresses are failing, but lookups for system users is successful.

Dovecot is setup to use system users, so my dovecot.conf has

```
 userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

and

```
passdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

I have auth debug enabled.

For example, I have a user called webmaster, and using doveadm user for "webmaster" works as follows:

```
#doveadm user webmaster
userdb: webmaster
  system_groups_user: webmaster
  uid       : 1020
  gid       : 1020
  home      : /home/webmaster
```

However using doveadm user to lookup webmaster@myregisteredname.com fails as follows:

```
# doveadm user webmaster@myregisteredname.com
userdb lookup: user webmaster@myregisteredname.com doesn't exist
```

This is resulting in incoming mail for webmaster@myregisteredname.com to bounce with an "unknown user" error.

Here's the failure logged in /var/log/maillog:

```
Apr 16 20:13:35 www dovecot: auth: passwd(webmaster@myregisteredname.com): unknown user
```

Here's the failure logged in /var/log/debug.log:

```
Apr 16 20:13:35 www dovecot: auth: Debug: master in: USER       1       webmaster@myregisteredname.com  service=doveadm
Apr 16 20:13:35 www dovecot: auth: Debug: passwd(webmaster@myregisteredname.com): lookup
Apr 16 20:13:35 www dovecot: auth: Debug: master out: NOTFOUND  1
```

The users and their home directories were imported from another server and the users were setup using the vipw tool.  I'm sure there's someting I missed on the import that's not "linking" the system user with the dovecot lookup.

Any ideas about what that something may be?

EDIT:
Using BillThor's advice, I updated dovecot.conf as follows:

```
#doveconf -n passdb userdb
passdb {
  args = username_format=%n
  driver = passwd
}
userdb {
  args = username_format=%n
  driver = passwd
}
```

However, now, doveadm user fails in a different fashion:

```
#doveadm user webmaster@pantronx.com
doveadm(root): Error: userdb lookup(webmaster@myregisteredname.com): Disconnected unexpectedly
doveadm(root): Fatal: userdb lookup failed for webmaster@myregisteredname.com
```

And, it no longer works for users without a domain:

```
#doveadm user webmaster
doveadm(root): Error: userdb lookup(webmaster): Disconnected unexpectedly
doveadm(root): Fatal: userdb lookup failed for webmaster
```

When I get the above messages, the following is in /var/log/maillog:

```
Apr 17 17:30:02 www dovecot: auth: Fatal: passdb passwd: Unknown setting: username_format=%u
Apr 17 17:30:02 www dovecot: master: Error: service(auth): command startup failed, throttling
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Userids in dovecot using passdb don't include the domain.  The userid the user should use is the local part, not the full email address.

The checks that are passing and failing are working as expected. Setting `auth_username_format=%n` before the password db definition does work.  The domain is not validated though.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but that doesn't work, either.  I've edited my question with the updated results.

Comment: @Coleman: Found a working solution for Dovecot 1.2.  Should work for Dovecot 2 as well. See edit to my response.  Found the solution in default configuration file for ubuntu.

Answer (score 16):

I am using Ubuntu Server 12.04 and I tried the above solutions. However, I found that simplest and easiest way was in 10-auth.conf to set

```
auth_username_format = %n
```

I use PAM for the authentication which is the default in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Where in that file?

Answer (score 4):

> auth_username_format = %n

breaks virtual domains on the same server, better idea is to use a conditional ( should work since 2.2.33 )

(see: https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/config_file/config_variables/ )

i'm using:

> auth_username_format=%{if;%d;eq;hostname.startdedicated.de;%Ln;%Lu}

which is working fine. However you can use %n instead %Ln and %u instead %Lu, if you are using usernames in uppercase or uppercase/lowercase mix. change hostname.startdedicated.de to fqdn-hostname of your server.

Comment: You are my hero!! At least for today :). I literally spent five hair-pulling hours trying to get virtual users to co-exist alongside system users before I stumbled upon your answer. Thank you!!!

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked for me. I wonder how this situation was handled before this feature was implemented? Address re-writing perhaps? Also the dovecot config section with info on conditionals is quite hidden!

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that Dovecot 2.1 either broke this solution or has changed the expected behavior.

I've traced the same authorization error to the userdb:

```
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

When a local user (non-virtual) receives an email via exim->lmtp it includes the domain.  Defining auth_username_format=%Ln does fix local delivery, but it breaks virtual deliveries.  The offered fix of adding args = username_format seems to be ignored:

```
userdb {
  driver = passwd
  args = username_format=%n
}
```

and the logs include a warning

```
Apr  4 11:24:57 moe dovecot: auth: Warning: userdb passwd: Move templates args to override_fields setting
```

Interestingly, using passwd-file **does work**, but auth is mad that the passwd file is owned by root.

```
userdb {
  driver = passwd-file
  args = username_format=%n /etc/passwd
}

Apr  4 11:26:12 moe dovecot: auth: Error: passwd-file /etc/passwd: User root has invalid UID '0'
Apr  4 11:26:12 moe dovecot: auth-worker(6855): Error: passwd-file /etc/passwd: User root has invalid UID '0'
```

Answer (score 1):

`passwd-file: Unknown setting:  username_format`
For me the reason was extra space:

```
passdb {
  driver = passwd-file
  args = scheme=SHA256-CRYPT **extra-space-here**username_format=%u /etc/dovecot/users
}
```

i.e. I had two spaces between CRYPT and uesrname.