# What options exist for changing usernames transparently in Webmail?

Tags: dovecot, webmail

Currently, we have a fully working POP/IMAP/Webmail system (using Dovecot and Roundcube) that is a gleaming tower of perfection in its intended design. We have thousands of customers who belong to a "default" domain (I'll call it ourdomain.com), and successfully log in with a username and password. We have a few thousand more who own domains that we host, and they log in successfully with their full e-mail address and password (call it customerdomain.com). It's been this way since the 1990s, with a lot of entrenched customer configuration.

The problem is now that people are used to logging into web forms with a full e-mail address, people who use ourdomain.com have to be reminded to log into webmail using *only* their username. This is a call our tech support department gets several times a week (and even I am guilty of doing this, I just don't call tech support about it), and probably should be eliminated with some kind of software solution.

So how do we get either Roundcube or Dovecot to recognise "username@ourdomain.com" as "username" instead, without having to change everyone's actual username in our system? But **only** do that if the domain is "ourdomain.com" and **not** "customerdomain.com". Keep in mind that any custom coding we do will have to be re-implemented every time we do security upgrades, and we would only consider that option as the last possible choice.

TL;DR:

We need this logic:

```
if $email contains @ourdomain.com
{
    remove @ourdomain.com;
    submit to roundcube;
} else {
    submit to roundcube;
}
```

Comment: Yup. Solution is there too.

Comment: No, it's not a dupe. I saw that question before I asked this one. It's actually the reverse situation. Logging in with just the username part of the e-mail address is not a problem - if the user@ourdomain.com address exists. If it's user@hosteddomain.com, then they need to use the full e-mail address. Customers should be able to log in with **either** Username = user or Username = user@ourdomain.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem can be tackled either in roundcube, dovecot or your username-backend.

1. Roundcube has option to **auto append domain parts if no domain provided** (as proposed by [Kondybas](https://serverfault.com/users/110736/kondybas)). But it won't too useful in your case. Of course you can patch roundcube (with PHP language) to adding your logic.
2. Dovecot has option to **strip domain** (as proposed in  [Dovecot user lookup fails when using username@domain format](https://serverfault.com/questions/260488/dovecot-user-lookup-fails-when-using-usernamedomain-format)) but it can't do conditional stripping (e.g. strip domain if domain = @ourdomain.com). Of course you can patch dovecot (with C language) to adding your logic.
3. Username-backend is also option too. You don't give the backend you use (either SQL, LDAP, custom engine). I can imagine that you have username column that have two format *with and without domain*. Now, you can convert all username without domain become username@ourdomain. You can combine this process with option 1 (roundcube auto append domain) so either username and username@ourdomain can login.

Comment: Option number three is one that I had never considered before, thank you. Modifying software to suit our needs could technically be an option too, but the need for frequent security updates makes that kind of thing a huge pain in the butt. Adding users with the same mailbox is a far more graceful solution.

Answer (score 3):

`RoundCube` have an option called `username_domain`

```
// Automatically add this domain to user names for login
// Only for IMAP servers that require full e-mail addresses for login
// Specify an array with 'host' => 'domain' values to support multiple hosts
// Supported replacement variables:
// %h - user's IMAP hostname
// %n - hostname ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
// %t - hostname without the first part
// %d - domain (http hostname $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] without the first part)
// %z - IMAP domain (IMAP hostname without the first part)
// For example %n = mail.domain.tld, %t = domain.tld
$config['username_domain'] = '';
```

If you have used subdirectory (like `ourdomain.tld/roundcube`) set this option to the

```
$config['username_domain'] = '%n';
```

If you have used subdomains (like `mail.domain.tld`) set this option to the

```
$config['username_domain'] = '%t';
```

When user provide his full email as login, that email will be used without any changes. If domain part is omitted, `RoundCube` will use the URL-domain for completion.
Also there is number of neat options in the roundcube's config.

Comment: No, this is backwards. Customers who use our domain do *not* include the @ourdomain.com part, they just log in with "myuser". Customers with virtual domain hosting include their full e-mail address.